# not continuous functional and the normed space (general case)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $\varphi :X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be linear and not continuous. Show that there exists such sequence $\left\{ x_n\right\}\subset X$, such that $\Vert x_n\Vert\rightarrow 0$ and $|\varphi(x_n)|\rightarrow\infty$, when $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I know that in linear operators between normed space, the boundess is the same as the countinuity. I did such excercises for concrete functionals, then the solution was just finding the counterexample (example of the sequence which is not bounded in the nbhd of $0$).

But what in general case? Maybe this excercise, in other words, is showing what I mentioned above, that not continuous functionals are not bounded?

Comment: If your functional is not bounded then for any $n$ there must be a vector $x_n$ so that $|\phi(x_n)|≥ n^2\,\|x_n\|$ (do you see why if this were not the case the functional must be bounded?). Do you see how this helps you?

Comment: the inequality looks like, hmm, the result of using contraposition on the definition of boundness?

Comment: Yes, the contraposition of the statement of the inequality is that there must exist an $n$ so that $|\phi(x)|≤n^2\|x\|$ for all $x$, implying boundedness.

Comment: yes, but the main problem I have is probably that this excercise sounds for me, like repeating definisions. From unboundness we got your inequality (using contraposition of the other definition) and so on..
u know what I mean? just using equivalence definitions :)

Comment: Often these kinds of exercises follow from unpacking definitions in the right way. I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: ok, but so I don't see how this inequality helps :)

Comment: Show that $\frac1n \frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|}$ is a convergent sequence. What happens to its images under $\phi$?

Comment: I finally see, thanks a lot :)